# Ruby и Telegram bot. Ответ на вопрос через виртуальную клавиатуру

Tags: ruby, telegram-bot

Использую Ruby для работы c telegram bot
Нужно выводить несколько вариантов ответа и получая ответ, понимать что это ответ на некий вопрос.

```
answers =
Telegram::Bot::Types::ReplyKeyboardMarkup
  .new(keyboard: a, one_time_keyboard: true)
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|
     bot.api.send_message(chat_id: 76948168, text:"question", reply_markup: force, reply_to_message_id: message)
     puts message.message_id.to_s + " " + message.text + " " + message.reply_to_message.to_s
  end
end
```

Если пользователь нажимает на один из ответов клавиатуры, например А

получаю вывод
546 A

И не видно что это А - ответ на запрос question

Comment: Я вешал на пользователя состояние в БД, т.е. когда мы задаем вопрос можно сделать пометку в базе данных, а когда от него приходит сообщение, проверяем не должен ли он ответить на него. Есть несколько библиотек для работы с конечными автоматами, я копал там. Возможно есть другой путь реализации.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я думал о таком пути, но вдруг есть стандартный способ.

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено.
метод sendmessage возращает резултат в виде объекта. с этого объекта можно получить данные необходимые

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|
     msg = bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text:"Вопрос жи есть", reply_markup: answers, reply_to_message_id: message)
     jojo = msg["result"]
     puts jojo["text"].to_s
     puts message.message_id.to_s + " " + message.text + " " + jojo["text"].to_s
  end
end
```